# Сортировка динамического массива

Tags: сортировка, pascal, динамические-массивы

Не получается отсортировать одномерный динамический массив по возрастанию, постоянно выдает ошибку:

```
var
    mas :array of integer;
    n, i, k, j, res :int64;
begin
    AssignFile(input, 'input.txt');
    reset(input);
    read(n);

    AssignFile(output, 'output.txt');
    rewrite(output);
    Setlength(mas, n);

    for i := 0 to n-1 do 
    begin
        read(k);
        mas[i] := k;
    end;

    //Сама сортировка
    //**
    for i := 0 to n-1 do
        for k := 1 to n-i do
            if mas[k] > mas[k+1] then
            begin
                res := mas[k];
                mas[k] := mas[k+1];
                mas[k+1] := res;
            end;
    //**

    for i := 0 to n-1 do 
    begin
        write(mas[i], ' ');
    end;  

    CloseFile(input); 
    CloseFile(output);
end.
```

Comment: Какую же ошибку?

Comment: Выдает ошибку времени выполнения, так как индекс находился за пределами массива. Никак не могу решить этот вопрос

Comment: на какой строчке?

Comment: 20 строчка с ошибкой постоянно. Суть такая, в файле числа, первое число делаю длиной массива, дальше вгоняю числа в массив, они там находятся, и даже выводятся, но не сортируются. Пытался добавить n-i-1, но тоже не помогло

Comment: У вас массив n-элементов, с индексацией от 0 до n-1. n-i-1 должно было помочь и k надо начинать с 0. Вот ваш пузырек (с индексацей от 1 до N) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Простой пример: `Сама сортировка` - `i = 0`, тогда `k от 1 до n - 0`, а индексы массива закончатся на `n - 1`. `n-i-1` - тоже не поможет, потому что потом происходит `mas[k+1]` = `mas[n - 0 + 1]`

Comment: попробуй так: `for i := 0 to n-2 do for k := i to n-1 do`

Comment: @slippyk нет, k := 0 до n-i-1 мы же "сверху-вниз" заполняем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так должно выглядеть:

```
var
...
  flag: boolean;

for i := 0 to n - 2 do
begin
    flag := True;
    for k := 0 to n - 2 do
    begin
        if mas[k] > mas[k + 1] then
        begin
            res := mas[k];
            mas[k] := mas[k + 1];
            mas[k + 1] := res;
            flag := False;
        end;
    end;
    if flag then break;
end;
```